How to redirect multiple files to multiple folders based on their name using ADF
I wanted to know how to redirect the multiple files into multiple folders in Data Lake using Azure Datafactory.
For example, My file is bag.csv, then I can redirect it into TotalBags kind of folder in Data Lake Gen 2.
Please help me to resolve this.
Need a perfect solution for this problem


For example, My file is bag.csv, then I can redirect it into TotalBags kind of folder in Data Lake Gen 2

To do this, first you need to get the list of all source files using Get meta data activity, and then use a For-each activity to iterate through that list which copied each individual file to its directory depending upon its name.
First, create a Binary dataset with path till your source files folder and give this to the Get meta data activity.

This will give the list of files like below.
"childItems": [
        {
            "name": "bag.csv",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "bag.json",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "book.csv",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "book.json",
            "type": "File"
        }
    ]

Give this ChildItems array @activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems to a For-each activity.
Inside For-each, take a copy activity with two new binary datasets in which one is for the source files, and another is for the target location.
In the source binary dataset, give the dynamic expression @item().name as file path.

In the target binary dataset, use the below expressions as folder path and file path repectively.
Folder path - @concat('Total',toUpper(first(item().name)),substring(split(item().name,'.')[0],1,add(length(split(item().name,'.')[0]),-1)),'s')

filepath - @item().name


Give these two datasets as source and sink datasets for the copy activity inside For-each.

Now, debug the pipeline and the source files will be copied to the target folders. It will create the target folders if not exists.

